# perl module installation shared host

Tags: perl-module

My shared hosting is missing two Perl modules required by Amazon SES Scripts. They are:

Digest::SHA and XML::LibXML

I downloaded Digest::SHA from [here](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/M/MS/MSHELOR/Digest-SHA-5.62.tar.gz) and XML::LibXML from [here](http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/P/PA/PAJAS/XML-LibXML-1.70.tar.gz)

Extracted, and uploaded LibXML.pm and SHA.pm to my custome directory (my_perl_lib).

I have added:

```
use lib "/var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib";
```

to the second line to the perl script.

I get this:

```
Can't locate XML/LibXML.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009
/html/my_perl_lib /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5
/site_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8/i386-linux-
 thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8
/i386-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8 .) at ./ses-get-stats.pl line 24.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./ses-get-stats.pl line 24.
```

Please advise.

**Updated:**

thanks, i created the directory, the error gone, but i faced another one:

```
Can't locate loadable object for module XML::LibXML in @INC (@INC contains: /var/chroot
/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib .......) at /var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009
/html/my_perl_lib/XML/LibXML.pm line 153 BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /var/chroot
/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib/XML/LibXML.pm line 153. Compilation failed in require
 at ./ses-get-stats.pl line 24. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./ses-get-stats.pl line 24.
```

**Updated:**

thanks again for your reply.

here are the results:

```
-bash-3.2$ perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib
enable native perl UTF8
running xml2-config...ok (2.6.26)
looking for -lxml2... no
looking for -llibxml2... no
libxml2 not found
Try setting LIBS and INC values on the command line
Or get libxml2 from 
http://xmlsoft.org/
If you install via RPMs, make sure you also install the -devel
RPMs, as this is where the headers (.h files) are.

Also, you may try to run perl Makefile.PL with the DEBUG=1 parameter
to see the exact reason why the detection of libxml2 installation
failed or why Makefile.PL was not able to compile a test program.
-bash-3.2$
```

Answer (score 1):

It needs to be inside an "XML" directory...  IE, make sure that LibXML.pm is actually in `/var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib/XML/LibXML.pm`.

**Updated:**

You probably need to do a full local install of the perl module, and the shared object that accompanies it.  You can do this by using:

```
# extract sources
# cd source-directory
# perl Makefile.PL INSTALL_BASE=/var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib
# make
# make install
```

This will install everything needed into that directory.  Then in the script, reference both of these paths:

```
use lib '/var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib/lib/perl5';
use lib '/var/chroot/home/content/09/6758009/html/my_perl_lib/lib/perl5/i386-linux-thread-multi/auto';
```

Note that you'll likely need to change the architecture of the `i386-linux-thread-multi` part of that line.  That's where the .so file is installed.

Comment: I've updated it with a more complete description of how to do a full local install.